# Android issue rise after release

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

I've uploaded my first android app to the market, it contains some sounds, some images and some gallery projects. That makes the project size almost 9.5MB. i've used mp3 and png formats for sound and images respectively. I exported the project by right click to project -> Android Tools -> Export signed application .. and the process goes on. 
Now when user downloads the app, it expands after installation, and the size exceeds to 24MB. Also it has some bugs which can be seen in the below picture:

[image]

What are the issues ?? Thanks in advance..

Comment: What bugs are we supposed to see in the picture? And what does Adobe Reader have to do with your app?

Comment: I've mentioned the bug in the question. What should i do to reduce the size and there are two buttons for the app in the storage section, i.e. Clear Cache and Move to Phone.. the picture of adobe reader is for comparison between my app and adobe app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application can't be moved to the SD-card, because you have to explicitly enable that first. To do so, use the [`android:installLocation`-attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) in the `<manifest>`-tag of your Android Manifest. Also see: [How to enable app being moved to sdcard (and support android < 2.2 still)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023068/how-to-enable-app-being-moved-to-sdcard-and-support-android-2-2-still)

---

For the "expanding after installation"-part: Have you checked the size if your (uncompressed) application on your dev-machine? You can extract the build `.apk`-file with 7zip (for example) to see what size it becomes.

To make Android optimize certain pieces of binary assets (for example your PNG-files), put them in the `/res/XXX`-subfolders rather then the older `/assets`-folder (because Android will optimize those):

> Bitmap files may be automatically optimized with lossless image
>   compression by the aapt tool during the build process. [...]

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap)

---

As the last point, your applications "Clear Data"-button is not activated, because you don't seem to have any application-data.

The "application data" does not include any binary resources your application brings with it. It does simply remove any data which is stored on the [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) for your application.

Comment: Nice explained! 1 more thing, i've used 4-5 sounds and their total size is 4.63MB and some images(30-40), whose size is 4.56MB.. any help regarding that?? They make the size of an app 9.56MB... how to reduce that

Comment: Have you checked that this is in fact the *uncompressed* size? I can't explain why it should grow by that much.

Comment: Well after extracting using 7zip, the file size changes from 9.43MB to 9.67MB....

Comment: My last idea would be using a file-manager or the adb-bridge to check what is taking up so much size in the applications internal-storage.